# ASP Rest Services with Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I am trying to building a REST Service with Stream input which I eventually want to save in a file on the server. My problem is that when I run the service I get 'EndPoint not found'

I am using VS 2010 with .NET 4.0

My Service Model is as under

```
<services>
  <service name="WCFService1.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="WCFService1.ITestService"
              behaviorConfiguration="web" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>      
</behaviors>
```

The code is very simple at this stage.
Service Code

```
namespace WCFService1
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]

  public interface ITestService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents);
  }
}
```

Function implementation

```
    public Stream UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
    {
        //save file
        var sr = new StreamReader(fileContents);
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World! " + text + fileName));
    }
```

svc file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WCFService1.TestService"   CodeBehind="TestService.svc.cs"   Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"%>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory". EDIT: Just for curiosity, why you return the uploaded Stream?

Comment: Also use instead UriTemplate = "UploadFile?fileName={fileName}", of UploadFile/{fileName}

Comment: On removing I get "For request in operation UploadFile to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream." Any idea how to resolve this?